# error while trying to install npm atob

Tags: node.js

I was trying to install npm atob in my project;but suddenly it is showing an error now as:

```
   Linux 2.6.23.17-88.fc7
   npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"  "atob"
   npm ERR! node v5.6.0
   npm ERR! npm  v3.8.8
   npm ERR! code CERT_NOT_YET_VALID
   npm ERR! certificate is not yet valid
   npm ERR! 
   npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
   npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
   npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
   npm ERR!     /home/www/project/npm-debug.log
```

but when i searched the most of them have answered as "Fix your system time"

Comment: my system time is correct

Answer (score 0):

try to correct your system time before to get a valid certification.
Else try to change the version of nodeJs

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
```

sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable

Answer (score 0):

The 'btoa-atob' module does not export a programmatic interface, it only provides command line utilities.
If you need to convert to Base64 you could do so using Buffer:

```
console.log(new Buffer('Hello World!').toString('base64'));
```

Reverse (assuming the content you're decoding is a utf8 string):

```
console.log(new Buffer(b64Encoded, 'base64').toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

The error code is **CERT_NOT_YET_VALID** -certificate is not yet valid, and it refers to ssl certificate.

This should fix this error

```
$ npm config set strict-ssl false
$ npm config set unsafe-perm true
$ npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```